# SQL Server select where sql_variant equal doesn't work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008

I have a column called `varEnteredValue` of datatype `sql_Variant`.

When I execute the following select statement I don't get anything

```
SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE varEnteredValue = 1
```

*Notice* I have many values with value 1 in this column

**Question**

How can I fix this issue? Do I need to convert data type ?

Comment: Are you sure?  I can't replicate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb0da/1 -- I wouldn't recommend storing with that data type...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You need to convert the value from `SQL_VARIANT` to `INT`.
2. You need to be careful about how you convert the values, since not every value in the column will necessarily be convertible to an `INT`, and it can be difficult to predict whether SQL Server will filter first or try to convert first. You need to test first if the value is numeric, and in order to do that, you must explicitly convert it to a string.

Here is an example that works around both issues:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), varEnteredValue)) = 1 
  THEN CONVERT(FLOAT, varEnteredValue) ELSE 0 END = 1;
```

Why are you using `SQL_VARIANT`?

Comment: i got the following error : Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type sql_variant is invalid for argument 1 of isnumeric function.

Comment: @Mina yes, sorry, I should have added a 2a. Please try with the explicit convert.

Comment: Got this error now : Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3.3' to data type int.

Comment: Try FLOAT instead... that should cover up [all of the problems with ISNUMERIC()](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html). In SQL Server 2012 you'll be able to use [`TRY_CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) which is much more appropriate.

Comment: @Mina please don't post code in the comments. If you want help with a *specific* case then please enter the table structure and sample data in the question. Also let us know how this value 1000022 got into the table.

Comment: it got into the database as sql_variant

Comment: I know that it is sql_variant. I'm asking how did it get there... did you use an INSERT statement, the Edit all rows grid, your application, something else...